# retrieve an array instead of key:val (laravel / eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This query:

```
$ids = EnergyMeters::leftJoin('meteringpoint_energymeter_relation', 'energymeter.id', '=', 
'meteringpoint_energymeter_relation.meterId')
                    ->where('id', '=', $meterPointId)
                    ->where('Deleted', '=', '0')
                    ->select('energymeter.id')
                    ->orderBy('name')
                    ->get();
```

gives me some ids as a result (structured as key, val)

```
[{"id":"03cd0c39-a51c-41a0-bbe3-37ae641d051e"},{"id":"0ebf61e7-b751-4931-b737-d8f71297e499"}, {"id"}, '...']
```

However I only need the ids as an array for this new sum-query:

```
Data::select(array(DB::RAW('sum(v1) as sumV1', 'sum(v2) as sumV2')))
            ->whereIn('id', $ids)
            ->where('PointOfTime', '>', $from)
            ->where('PointOfTime', '<=', $to + 86400)
            ->get();
```

Any eloquent solutions for this? Otherwise I would loop over the key and val array and push they value to a new array. Not that smart?

// edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: How are you getting those results in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a function (its just not in the official docs)

I found this in the source of Laravel:

```
/**
 * Get an array with the values of a given column.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return array
 */
public function lists($column, $key = null)
{
    // ... lots of code ...
}
```

So try `->lists('id');`

Comment: You're welcome. It often helps to quickly look at the API or the full source of the classes. Unfortunately the Laravel docs are far away from being complete.

Comment: Yes, this is true - however it is a really solid framework. (I still need some websocket pushs for notifications ;))

Answer (score 3):

On the first query results set use;

```
$data = Data::select(array(DB::RAW('sum(v1) as sumV1', 'sum(v2) as sumV2')))
        ->whereIn('id', $ids)
        ->where('PointOfTime', '>', $from)
        ->where('PointOfTime', '<=', $to + 86400)
        ->get();

$ids = $data->lists('id');
```

Notice the `lists('id')` this will give you the array you want. Then you can pass the results into the other query.

Comment: Wow that was close ;)

Answer (score 2):

### 'Lists' has been renamed to 'pluck'

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results says:

> **Retrieving A List Of Column Values** If you would like to retrieve a Collection containing the values of a single column, you may use the
>   pluck method. In this example, we'll retrieve a Collection of role
>   titles:

```
$titles = DB::table('roles')->pluck('title');

foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo $title;
}
```